# Referencing a programatically created UINavigationBar from within a XIB

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I got some of this code from another stackoverflow answer of how to add UINavbars to a UIToolBar

I do feel a little dumb here because I cant figure out how to reference a newly created NavController from the nib that I want it to display... this is what I am doing. I know I must have mixed something up here :(

In my app delegate I created the array of controllers:

```
UINavigationController *rvc_tools = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
initWithRootViewController: navController_tools]; 

UINavigationController *rvc_settings = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController_settings]; 

aboutIVacation* vc_about = [[aboutIVacation alloc] init]; 

myCurrent *mycurrentpage = [[myCurrent alloc] init]; 
UINavigationController *rvc_mysynchpage = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController_synch];
```

//And then I added it to the tab bar:

```
<code> NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: mycurrentpage,  rvc_tools,rvc_settings, vc_about, rvs_mysynchpage, nil];</code>
```

[iVacationTabBar setViewControllers: controllers animated:NO];
So now if I want rvc_mysynchpage to load my xib called "synch" how do I tell it to load that and once I am in my xib called synch and I have a button I want to push that shows pushes another view on top to do something, how do I have it push the new view.

If I try to call rvc_mysynchpage it will tell me its undeclared....

Comment: Your view controller should be loading the XIB file.  How are you initiating navController_synch ?  This is what needs to be loaded with:  navController_synch = [[??class of navController?? alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"synch" bundle:nil];

Comment: I have 5 tab buttons. Each Tab button displays a view. With 3 of the buttons I need nav controllers to be able to handle multiple views so in my readings I came up with a way (as shown above) to actually have the tab bar load a navcontroller instead of a viewcontroller.1

Comment: Sorry this got posted too early: 1) How and where do I initally push the view onto the nav stack and 2) once its pushed from within the code itself (in the .m file of the view controller), how do I reference that nav controller that was programmatically created in my app deletgate... (I tried adding it as an import, and even doing shared delegate but it never works)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out!!!!

To push a view controller on to the stack, it knows automatically what nav controller called it their and has that reference to it, you just do this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nameofcontroller animated: YES];
```